# How do I get results to open in new tab?

Tags: javascript, rest

I've made several edits to this line, but they do not appear to be working.

`html = html + "< a href='" + this.LinkingUrl + target="_blank"+"'>" + this.Name`

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Production_Library/communication management')/files?$select=LinkingURL,Name&$orderby=LinkingURL",
type: "GET",
headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
cache:false,                
success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var html = "";
        $(data.d.results).each(function(){
            html = html + "" + this.Name + "
" ;
        });
        html += "";
        $("#listResult2").html(html)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be it:

```
html = html + "< a href='" + this.LinkingUrl + "' target='_blank' >" + this.Name + "</a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the ES6 template literals seems very handful for situations like this.

```
html += `<a href='${this.LinkingUrl}' target='_blank'>${this.Name}</a>`
```